# Is there a cross-browser solution for getSelection()?

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser

I need to make a comment mechanism in which user highlights a piece of text, clicks "comment this", and then does something. The Javascript code has to know **not only the selected text** (this is trivial), but also the anchorOffset, to know exactly from which to which character the text was selected.

I've found a [cross-browser solution](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html) that gives you the text. Is there a reliable way to get a [selection object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Selection) as it's described in DOM specs?

Comment: That object is not in the DOM specs, as you can see on [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html#link2). That page might also be helpful for a kind of cross-browser solution.

Comment: I'd suggest a workaround where you parse the node text for the selected text with `indexOf(selection)`, but I'm not exactly sure what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [IERange](http://code.google.com/p/ierange/), which creates a selection-like object in IE and adds a `getSelection()` method to `window`. I don't think it's perfect but it's about the best standalone Range/selection library there is that I've seen.

**Update**

I've been working on a Range/selection library called Rangy that goes beyond what IERange provides. There's an early release available at http://code.google.com/p/rangy.