# Javascript/Jquery - How do I get the element that the user has selected with their cursor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the user highlights the text within an `<h1>` with their cursor, how do I get that `<h1>` object?  Or if they selected text within an `<li>`, how do i get that `<li>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deal with `window.getSelection()`.

See

- See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076052/is-there-a-cross-browser-solution-for-getselection)
- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284443/storing-highlighted-text-in-a-variable)
- and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815202/insert-selected-text-on-the-page-into-textarea-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the selection on Document as,

```
dd = window.getSelection();
desiredElement = dd.focusNode.parentNode; // h1 or li or other 
desiredTag = desiredElement.tagName; // its tagname
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: +1 yeah! this works! but I'm afraid if this is cross-browser... ;)

Comment: Not, it's not cross-browser, it's far far away from beeing cross-browser.

@simplyharsh: You really should mention that in your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('h1').click(function(){
   alert(this); // `this` is the <h1> object clicked.
});
```

is there some tricky part I missed in your question?

Comment: I think he means if you select text within the object. I.e. in `<h1>Foo Rar</h1>`, if you just highlight `Rar`, then he wants to knock that <h1> is the DOM object with the highlighted text.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea - but then, how would you highlight? with the `DOM` I guess you should click then highlight.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent element of a selection in all modern mainstream browsers as follows. Bear in mind that Firefox allows multiple selections by default these days; this code will use only the first.

See also my answer here: [How can I get the DOM element which contains the current selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335252/how-can-i-get-the-dom-element-which-contains-the-current-selection/1336922#1336922)

```
function getSelectionContainerElement() {
    var sel, el;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt) {
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                el = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
                return (el.nodeType == 3) ? el.parentNode : el;
            }
        } else {
            // This happens in old versions of Safari. A workaround
            // exists, if you need it
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
        return document.selection.createRange().parentElement();
    }
}
```