# After double click word , how to insert word in database using php or jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am making application where i need to insert value which are double clicked.can any one suggest me how to insert a word in database after double click in any word in a paragraph.
Like
http://www.thefreedictionary.com

In this Website after double click it search the meaning of that word, but i have to insert double clicked value in database.Please help me if any body have idea.

thanks in advance

Comment: use jQuery ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321511/get-the-current-word-in-paragraph-on-click-event-in-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use AJAX preferably with jQuery. The process should work like this: dbclick->take data->initiate ajax request with POST to a PHP page->execute

Some sample code :

```
$('element').dblclick(function(){
  var data = //your handler here
  $.ajax({
     //code here
   });
});
```

Take a look at this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Check this also. Although I would recommend you search if it can be done with jquery. It will minimize your code size

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275761/how-to-get-selected-text-from-textbox-control-with-javascript

Answer (score 2):

On page load, initiate one function which listen for double click. 
You can get jquery for it easily.

On click post `selected text` i.e. `word` through post(preferable) or get method to page which performs database insertion.

Comment: @NirdoshShrestha: Welcome for next. you should up vote the answer if it helped you anyhow