# Get css from text at the position of the cursor

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to wrap up a really simple RTE for private purposes. I'd like to toggle the bold/italic/underline buttons when a user clicks in the text. I've been reading several posts but they all include a selection either selected by mouse or double click. Also jQuery's `select` works on a selection, and not a point where was clicked. I understand there's not really any css for a cursor location, so I would like to select the word where the user clicked.

How can I get the css properties of word from the index clicked? I'm using a div that's editable.

Some of the posts I've been reading:

1. [jQuery select()](https://api.jquery.com/select/)
2. [Get the current word in paragraph on click
   event in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321511/get-the-current-word-in-paragraph-on-click-event-in-jquery)

Comment: CSS is not dynamic and is just read and applied - so that is not a path. Seems like you would need to click and then span everything into an array and then based on click x and y find the span and get the data... but also doesn't sound possible.

Comment: `I'd like to toggle the bold/italic/underline buttons when a user clicks in the text.` emphasis a bit more ..

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik, for example when a word is bold, the bold button should be "active", visually clear that the text is bold.

Comment: @sheriffderek I think that would become a bit slow when there will be lots of text in the editor. Applying a `<span>` to each word sounds a bit aggresive.

Comment: Yes, it sounds terrible. Most TinyMCE text input areas - like in WordPress etc have what I think you are talking about. You can check into that - or maybe even use one.