# How to select a "word" from a string on click event

Tags: angular

I have a string and when i click on any word in a string then it should give another string from that clicked word onward back to the start of the string i.e.

str = 'this is a test string.'
After click on **"test"** word, the new string should be like that **'this is a test'** etc.

Currently, When I select the **whole word** then it gives the expected result but **not on 'click'**.

Also, in the following link they give the solution but it is in jquery and I want to implent in **Anguar 10**

[Get a word by single click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499865/get-a-word-by-single-click)

**app.component.html**

```
<textarea class="form-control  rows=10 cols=50 cstm-textarea" (click)="TargetPrefix($event)">
    This is a test string
</textarea>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
TargetPrefix(event) {

    const start = event.target.selectionStart;
    const end = event.target.selectionEnd;
    const result = event.target.value.substr(end - start, start);

    console.log("the clicked word in the string", result);

}
```

[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]

Thank you

**onClick**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjwKO.jpg

**Select**
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG6zT.jpg

Comment: show me how did you tried to make it work

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I insert the images, hopefully you understand. Otherwise i will try to explain more.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example of how to implement it in angular

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-prcewk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I just updated your `targetPrefix` method.

Comment: that is really good way to give answer to someone !

Comment: IThanks for your feedback. I checked the link but still getting just clicked word but I want  the whole string from the clicked word onward back of the string. For example, click on 'test' word then the result string should be 'this is a test' and if I click on 'is' word then the it should return 'this is'.              Currently, in the mentioned link, only  getting 'clicked word'

Comment: Here you have another example, in this one I added what you are looking for https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xffr3e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts (I tried to make the code readable enough to make easy to understand my approach)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already given in the link you've provided.

```
function TargetPrefix(event) {
  let s = window.getSelection();
  let start = event.target.selectionStart; // save cursor position

  s.modify('extend', 'backward', 'word');
  let b = s.toString();

  s.modify('extend', 'forward', 'word');
  let a = s.toString();

  console.log("the clicked word in the string", b + a);

  s.removeAllRanges();  //clear selection
  document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].selectionStart = start; // restore cursor
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @EvgenyV, But I want to implement in Angular10 not in js