# Add clicked words to string

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to add specific words to a string in an input box, when they are clicked on the page.

At the moment I have a solution as displayed here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/BvP4n/

There are currently two problems with this, and it would be great if I could get your advice to change them:

1. I need the `<span>` tags to cover the entirety of the text with one tag, but when clicked only the specific word that has been clicked is sent to the word string.
2. I need to place the words in an input box as part of a form, not a `<div>`.

Comment: The second is not possible this way, the first will only work if you wrap each word in a span

Comment: what's the purpose of 1. ?

Comment: @om_deshpande to avoid `<span>` tags around every individual word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/BvP4n/7/**

1. Don't include the spans in the markup
2. Split the initial text on spaces and make each word in to a separate span
3. Update your `target` selector to pick up these items
4. Instead of appending elements to a `<div/>` append the textual values to an `<input/>`

### Updated HTML

```
<p id="target_para">
   Here's an example of the thing you wanted to be made clickable.
</p>
<input type="text" id="display" />
```

### Updated Javascript

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var para, targets, display, words, clickHandler, updateList, i, j, cur;

    display = document.getElementById("display");
    para = document.getElementById("target_para");

    // Wrap every word in a span element
    para.innerHTML = '<span>' + para.innerText.replace(/ /g, '</span><span>') + '</span>';

    // Updated target
    targets = para.getElementsByTagName("span");
    words = [];

    // Handler for clicking a clickable element
    clickHandler = function () {
        var text = this.innerText || this.textContent,
            idx = words.indexOf(text);

        if (words.indexOf(text) < 0) {
            // If not already in list, add it
            words.push(text);
        } else {
            // Otherwise remove it
            words.splice(idx, 1);
        }
        updateList();
    };

    // Update display of word list
    updateList = function () {
        while (display.firstChild) {
            display.removeChild(display.firstChild);
        }

        // Set the input box value
        display.value = words.join(", ");
    };

    // Bind event handlers to clickable elements
    for (i = 0, j = targets.length; i < j; i++) {
        cur = targets[i];
        cur.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
    }
}());
```

Comment: How do I keep words that I add manually to the input box? Also how would I exclude full stops from the text transferred from `<p>` to `<input>`? Thank you.

Comment: To answer the first part: you will have to do some sort of comparison to remove only words in the available list and leave the rest in there (instead of simply over-writing the contents).. This really should have been part of your initial requirements.

Comment: Any suggestions, or should that be a completely new ticket?

Comment: @MissJaneE I suggest you start a fresh one!

Answer (score 0):

1) Use search option:

[Detect which word has been clicked on within a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563169/detect-which-word-has-been-clicked-on-within-a-text)

2) very simple code change: just add `<input type="text" id="test"/>` and in updateList method add:  `document.getElementById("test").value = words.join(", ");` see here: http://jsfiddle.net/BvP4n/