# Show span on hover over some word and replace on demand

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I'm working on a spellchecker plugin for TinyMCE (3.x series). When user clicks on plugin to spellcheck I take the editor's content and send it to server, then from server I send the data back with underlining the wrong words and a list of suggestions (which is hidden). It works fine and on TinyMCE interface I see wrong words with red underline.

Now I want to show list of suggestions when user hovers (left-click is also fine) over the wrong word so that he can pick the correct word and replace it with wrong word. Can anyone guide me how should I proceed on this?

Textarea content: `Fourr guys went to watc movie yesterday.`

HTML: `<p>Fourr guys went to watc movie yesterday.</p>`

After clicking on plugin the HTML becomes:

```
<p>
   <span style="color: red; text-decoration: underline;">Fourr</span>
   <span class="suggestions" style="display: none;">Fore Furor Furry Fourier Four Farr Fora Fury
   Fours Fire Firer Fuhrer Fiori Fourth Dourer Fouler Foyer Fayre Fairer Fr Flour Fort Furrow  
   Purr</span> guys went to 
   <span style="color: red; text-decoration: underline;">watc</span>
   <span class="suggestions" style="display: none;">WAC Wac Wat watch Watt watt WATS</span>
   movie yesterday.
</p>
```

Comment: Probably using JQuery? If so - I would consider some overlay div with (select) values, event delegation on click would change selected text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
 $('span').not('.suggestions').click(function(){
     $(this).next('span').toggle();
 })
```

And the you'll need some sort of list from which you can select your option. Because from span it will be harder to select, but still possible, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563169/detect-which-word-has-been-clicked-on-within-a-text).

For changing just save your clicked span in some sort of variable and then replace the text in in with chosen one like

```
var $this;
 $('span').not('.suggestions').click(function(){
     $this = $(this);
     $(this).next('span').toggle();
 })
```

And then after choosing a word

```
$this.text(yourTextChosenVar)
```

**UPD** Added [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/71ka00n7/5/) with a little bit formated suggestions list.

**UPD2** Complete [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/71ka00n7/6/)

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising, I'll try and update with results. BTW here's the fiddle with what you suggested: http://jsfiddle.net/chankeypathak/71ka00n7/2/

Comment: I have made this: http://jsfiddle.net/chankeypathak/71ka00n7/4/ Now how can I replace the wrong word?

Comment: Amazing! Thanks. That's a complete answer to my question.