# get specific word on click event for SVG Text element

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

In [this example](https://gist.github.com/maxArturo/8d9609cfb14f148ddb8c), I trigger a `onClick()` event in a SVG `text` element through d3.js to do a search based on the text content. See excerpt below:

```
gnode.append("text")
    .attr("x", 14)
    .attr("y", ".31em")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.Title;
    })
    .on("click", function(d) {
      if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return;
      clickedNode = d;
      var words = d.Title.toLowerCase().split(" ").filter(function(w) {
        return w != keyword;
      });
      console.log(words);
      updateNodes(words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]);
    });
```

In the code above, I don't actually know what word was clicked on - I just use a refernce keywoad and choose another one *at random*. In reality, what I'd like to do is get the **specific** word that was clicked on, and use it as input to my listeners.

My question is the following:

#### Given a SVG `Text` element, how can I determine the word that was clicked on within the element for use in events?

ps: There are ways of doing this with regular HTML, such as the ones provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563169/detect-which-word-has-been-clicked-on-within-a-text). Short of generating a bunch of discrete `<text>` elements and offseting them from a `g` element, I've no clue how I could capture the specific word without using an enclosed element. I believe jQuery wouldn't let me do this either within SVG.

Comment: What's wrong with the html way?

Comment: If you don't want to use separate elements, you'd have to get the position of the click and determine the distance to each word to choose the closest one.

Comment: Robert, There's no good way of doing it through HTML as far as I know, short of wrapping everything in span tags - which don't play well with SVG. My first thought was to add individual words in text elements offset to simulate them being in the same line, but that seems too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm nearly certain that clicks on a `text` element are atomic. But, you ought to be able to use a [tspan element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan). Make one for each word and hang event handlers off them (or on the parent `text` node and use event delegation). Bonus, you can style each word individually to make them look clickable.

I haven't tried this, it *should* work, let me know if it doesn't.