# Fetching Words with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am more or less a newby and hobby coder. I am currently working on a project where I want the following to happen:

If a user clicks on a certain word on a website, I want Javascript (pref. Ajax) to fetch the word and e.g. spit it out in the console.

Does Ajax offer something simmilar or how would you build that in JS?

Comment: When you say fetch you mean what? Search in some API, e.g., dictionary? Or just print the same word in the console?

Comment: well, for now I would be happy with printing the word to the console. The overall goal would be to search in a translation API (google, bing etc.).

Comment: if you just want to log the word you just clicked you don't need ajax

Comment: I searched the entire [Ajax](http://www.colgatecommercial.com/brands.aspx?brand=Ajax) product line but I found nothing that has any use case for words.

Comment: This has nothing to do with AJAX :/

Comment: Then you might want to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563169/detect-which-word-has-been-clicked-on-within-a-text

Comment: thanks, I will take a look at this!

Comment: For clarification, AJAX is when you make a request (to a different webserver or your own) that does't reload the screen. There a few APIs (fetch, xmlhttprequest) provided by JavaScript to do this, and it allows you to efficiently load dynamic information without reloading the whole page.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Just to clarify, I actually meant JQuery. Due to work and studies, my last coding session has been a while - So, I really start lacking the damn basics. Thanks!