# Chrome extensions get information from the webpage

Tags: javascript, plugins, google-chrome-extension

I am writing chrome extension. My purpose is when someone clicks on a word in any page, I want to get that sentence in my code. I have found getClick function for chrome extension, but I do not know how to get the sentence which involves the clicked word? Or maybe there exists any other ways to do this?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a similar problem that was solved:
[Detect which word has been clicked on within a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563169/detect-which-word-has-been-clicked-on-within-a-text)

your can also try defining your own function on a span in case there is a specific word you want to identify when clicked on
attach your function this way:
onclick = myfunction(this)
this will hold all the information you need

if you will explain your question with more details I may be able to help you a bit more

Comment: Thanks! What I want is for example, someone is browsing on this website    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_Ocean, and clicks on the word "kilometers" in the first sentence of the page. Then I want to get the whole sentence "The Atlantic Ocean is the second largest of the world's oceans, with an area of about 106,460,000 square kilometers (41,100,000 square miles)."

Comment: there may be a more elegant solution from what im about to propose, and ill try to think of one and will write it here but for now this is what i can think of from the back of my head:  scrape the <p> elements inside the page, and insert a span that contains each sentence in the p element. for each span give a function that will display its innerHTML upon clicking it. makes sense?