# Detect which word is clicked within a paragraph in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a paragraph with some text that I am showing to a user. How do I detect the word that the user clicks on within the paragraph? For example, if a user clicks 'green' on a page, how could I detect that they specifically clicked on 'green'?

```js
const str = 'The sky is blue. The grass is green. The stop sign is red.'

const handleClick = () => {
  alert(e.target.value);
}

const Content = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p onClick={handleClick()}>{str}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Does this post answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563169/detect-which-word-has-been-clicked-on-within-a-text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect which word has been clicked on within a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563169/detect-which-word-has-been-clicked-on-within-a-text)

Comment: You might need to split the string. Put it in separate span's and and onClick on each of them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51615812/14104

Comment: @DanielBeck @Cybershadow No. I cannot use `s.modify()` in React. Further, I dont think DOM manipulation is recommended in React outside of the framework.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Seems to be working https://jsfiddle.net/xg51qfvu/1/

Comment: DOM manipulation is to be avoided, yes; but reading from `window.getSelection()` is not manipulating the DOM.  (`Selection.modify()` is not necessary; it was only mentioned in passing in one of the answers on the linked question.)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...

```
const str = 'The sky is blue. The grass is green. The stop sign is red.'

const handleClick = (s) => {
    alert(s);
}

return (
    <div>
        {
            str.split(' ').map(s => {
                return <span onClick={() => handleClick(s)}>{s}&nbsp;</span>
            })
        }
    </div>
);
```